# Lambda Where clause for Today and Tomorrow Dates

Tags: linq, lambda, where-clause

I have a Linq query that works with various Where clause additions.
But I also want to return the SingleDate for an Event where it is today or tomorrow.

```
Dances_Moderated = Dances_Moderated
  .Where(x => x.SingleDate == DateTime.Today) 
           && (x => x.SingleDate == DateTime.Today.AddDays(1))
  .ToList();
```

The code after the **&&** is underlined in red, and the error says:

> CS0023: Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'lambda expression'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `||` (**or**) instead of `&&` (**and**): `x.SingleDate.Date` should be either Today **or** tomorrow. I've added `.Date` in order to be on the safe side of the road: when we use `==` we want to compare dates only, not time parts.

```
Dances_Moderated = Dances_Moderated
  .Where(x => x.SingleDate.Date == DateTime.Today || 
              x.SingleDate.Date == DateTime.Today.AddDays(1))
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of errors in your code:
First: Syntax error,
Second: Business error. Your SingleDate never gonna equal to datetime.now. You should use greater and less operator to do that.

Your code should be like this:

```
Dances_Moderated = Dances_Moderated.Where(x => x.SingleDate >= DateTime.Today && x.SingleDate <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)).ToList();
```